# How to get the length of an Array which may contain a single element in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array which usually will hold a single record. I need to apply a condition check to ensure that the array size is not nil. However applying count methods on the array throws an error in my rails console.I have tried the following

```
nearest = Array.new
nearest = (Some expression to fetch records).first
nearest.size # throws error as undefined method size
nearest.count # throws error as undefined method count
nearest.length # throws error as undefined method length.
```

How do I fetch the length or at least setup an expression to check if the value is nil?

Comment: Please, go through docs before asking. [Array#`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-count). Also, always make sure you are calling a method *on the right object*.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You assign `Array.new` to `nearest` and then on the very next line you throw that array away and assign something else to `nearest`. This "something else" doesn't seem to be an array, but there is no way we can know what it is because you don't tell us. We *could* probably figure it out from the error message, but you don't tell us what that is, either. How are we going to help you fix your problem if you don't tell us what object you are having a problem with and what the error is?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I was not aware that when you call ".first" method on an array object, it no longer stays an error.  "The something else" is an array, but since I am still very new to rails, I made that blunder of calling ".first" on it. With due respect to you, there are others who understood the question and have give solutions to the answer which has already helped me rectify the prob.

Comment: Actually, I have the strong suspicion that the "something else" is *not* an array, but rather an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But, like I said, since you are not telling us what the "something else" is and you also don't tell us the error message, there is no way of knowing that. If it *were* an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, there are very likely better ways to achieve what you want, but since you don't tell us what it is, there is no way of knowing that either.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko As I have mentioned, I am still new to rails and am bound to make mistakes. I was unaware that when you call ".first" on an array object, the object no longer stays an array and I have been calling .size method on that object which is wrong. Part of the learning process. A little patience from the experts would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] that the array size is not `nil`

The array size can never be `nil`. It is an integer and it might be zero.

The problem with your code is that you call `size` not on the array itself, but on it’s first element, that *might be `nil`*.

To make your code work as expected, you probably want to either:

```
nearest = Array.new
if nearest.size > 0
  nearest = (Some expression to fetch records).first
  # DO STUFF
end
```

or, alternatively, check the `first` element to be not `nil` (the first element of array is always accessible, though it returns `nil` for empty arrays:

```
nearest = Array.new
nearest = (Some expression to fetch records).first
unless nearest.nil?
  # DO STUFF
end
```

Comment: `unless nearest.empty?` would be better for the first option.

Comment: @sawa yes, but I tried to remain as close to the OP’s code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
nearest = Array.new
nearest << Test.first

nearest.count
```

## or

```
objArray = []
objArray = Array.new
```

To push, push or use <<:

```
objArray.push 17
>>> [17]

objArray << 4
>>> [17, 4]
```